# Python While Loop: sum of all numbers but the greatest

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, sum

Hi so my problem is that i must create a function that asks the user to enter a series of
numbers greater than or equal to zero, one at a time. The user types end to indicate that
there are no more numbers. The function computes the sum of all the values entered
except for the maximum value in the series. (Think of this as dropping the highest
homework score from a series of homework scores.) The function then both prints the
sum and returns the sum. You may assume the user inputs are valid: they will either be a
number greater than or equal to zero, or the string end. Here are some examples of how
the function should behave:

```
>>> allButMax()
Enter next number: 20
Enter next number: 30
Enter next number: 40
Enter next number: end
The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: 50.0
50.0
>>> allButMax()
Enter next number: 1.55
Enter next number: 90
Enter next number: 8.45
Enter next number: 2
Enter next number: end
The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: 12.0
12.0
>>> x = allButMax()
Enter next number: 3
Enter next number: 2
Enter next number: 1
Enter next number: end
The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: 3.0
>>> print(x)
3.0
>>> allButMax()
Enter next number: end
The sum of all values except for the maximum value is: 0
0
```

can anyone help me with this?? so far i have this (also this has to be a while loop)

```
def allButMax():
    while True:
        number=float(input("Enter next number: "))
        if number="end":
            break
    "end"=0
```

what i dont know is that i dont know how to add every value other than the max value. how would the function know which value is the maximum value? Also would i have to use another while loop to add all numbers?

Comment: So? What's your problem?

Comment: That code isn't even close. Please do your own homework. Read the instructional materials if necessary (it is necessary).

Comment: Can you store values in temporary buffer?

Comment: If you cannot use temporary buffer, just add up all the values and keep track of max, when at the end just subtract the max value.

Comment: my problem is that i dont know how to add every value other than the max value.

Comment: how would the function know which value is the maximum value

Comment: also would i have to use another `while` loop to add all numbers?

Comment: It sounds like you have many questions, not just one. That cannot be wrapped up into a single "how do I do this assignment?" - it's too broad for this site. You'll have to do your own work.

Comment: `if number > maximum: maximum = number`

Comment: Can you use a list? You can then use `max` to find the greatest number in the list. Also, why are you setting a literal(`"end"`) equal to another literal(`0`)? That will not work, and Python will raise an error.

Comment: As step 1, you might want to print the value of a sum of all input values; don't worry about the max.

Comment: anytime i enter `"end"` into the line, it gives an error.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service. Please review your instructional materials, discuss with your classmates, and talk to your teacher.

Comment: Its just one page it doesnt matter

Comment: The error states: `number=float(input("Enter next number: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'end'`

Comment: @thesonyman101 - Did you just say that a little bit of plagiarism doesn't matter?

Comment: The error message is very clear here :).

Comment: why dont you just convert it to a float after

Comment: lol I'm just going to flag this question and hope it gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer out for this but then saw from a previous answer that I'm not meant to do that. It's true, you do need to do your homework and work this out yourself but here are a few pointers:

1. Your function operates within a while loop but you can track variables outside of the while loop, your "max_number" can be reassigned a differnt value each time you go through the loop:

   ```
   def allButMax():
       max_number = 0
       while True:
           print "running while loop"
           break
   ```
2. You don't need to use a list, the output number is simply all of the numbers added up minus the largest number.

   ```
   return total_numbers - max_numer
   ```
3. Your function needs to return a value so use the "return" keyword.
4. lastly, you might want to look up the "try" and "except" keywords to evaluate the user's input. Did the user give you a number or a string?

   ```
   try:
       int(user_input)
   except ValueError:
       #user input is a string
   ```

Hope this helps without giving away too much :)

All the best!

Comment: lol I did exactly that and that said it wasn't formatted right.

Comment: @thesonyman101 No not at all. You gave the code and no explanation. Nick gave _some_ code(not a full out solution) and gave an explanation. It helps when posting answers to ask yourself if and how this answer will be helpful to future visitors. If you cannot answer, don't post that answer ;)

Comment: so im having treouble being able to input `"end"` into the `Enter next number: ` line. is there a way to convert the string to a float???

Comment: You can use "try" and "except ValueError" to tell you if the user gave you a string or not. Once you know it is a string (ie except ValueError is executed) then you can evaluate the input knowing that it is a string (ie if input = "end" then do what you want to do, else if its a string other than "end" thebn that's invalid input and you can just run the loop again).